# Google Analytics Search and Replace Regexp Filter That Can Remove Port Numbers

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 referring sources in Google Analytics from a newsletter server: newsletter1.domain.com:80 and newsletter1.domain.com

I would like to combine the two sources so that there is only one referring source that looks like newsletter1.domain.com. Can anyone help me with the correct search and replace expression that will filter out the port number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace ":80$" by nothing "" on the hostname field

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and report back here

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work I am testing another solution